# error: 'null' was not declared in this scope when setting integer to 0 - photon/arduino C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I have some simple code below that errors in compilation with:

```
scorer.cpp: In function 'void loop()':
scorer.cpp:56:37: error: 'null' was not declared in this scope
         feeler2ConsecutivePresses = 0;
```

I have tried setting it to `NULL` instead of 0, and including the standard libraries. What am I missing (C++ beginner here)

```
int feeler1 = D0;
int feeler2 = D2;
int batteryLowIndicator = D4;
int pingFrequency = 5000;
unsigned long lastPing = millis();
bool batteryLow = false;
bool sentOnlineMessage = false;

int feeler1PreviousState;
int feeler2PreviousState;
int batteryLevelPreviousState;

int feeler1ConsecutivePresses;
int feeler2ConsecutivePresses;
int consecutivePressThreshold = 30; // 3 seconds

void setup() {
    pinMode(feeler1, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
    pinMode(feeler2, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
    pinMode(batteryLowIndicator, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {

    int feeler1Pressed = digitalRead(feeler1);
    int feeler2Pressed = digitalRead(feeler2);
    int batteryLevel = digitalRead(batteryLowIndicator);

    if (Particle.connected() && !sentOnlineMessage) {
        sentOnlineMessage = true;
        Particle.publish("online", "1", 60, PRIVATE);
    }

    if (feeler1Pressed == HIGH) {
        if (feeler1PreviousState == HIGH) {
            feeler1ConsecutivePresses += 1;
        } else {
            Particle.publish("scored", "1", 60, PRIVATE);
        }
    } else {
        feeler1ConsecutivePresses = 0;
    }

    if (feeler2Pressed == HIGH) {
        if (feeler2PreviousState == HIGH) {
            feeler2ConsecutivePresses += 1;
        } else {
            Particle.publish("scored", "2", 60, PRIVATE);
        }
    } else {
        feeler2ConsecutivePresses = 0;
    }

    if (feeler1ConsecutivePresses == consecutivePressThreshold
            && feeler2ConsecutivePresses == consecutivePressThreshold) {
        Particle.publish("endGame", null, 60, PRIVATE);
    }

    if (batteryLevel == LOW && batteryLevel != batteryLevelPreviousState) {
        Particle.publish("batteryLow", "1", 60, PRIVATE);
    }

    // Ping server every x seconds
    if (millis() - lastPing > pingFrequency) {
        Particle.publish("ping", "1", 60, PRIVATE);
        lastPing = millis();
    }

    feeler1PreviousState = feeler1Pressed;
    feeler2PreviousState = feeler2Pressed;
    batteryLevelPreviousState = batteryLevel;

    delay(100);
}
```

Comment: `Particle.publish("endGame", null, 60, PRIVATE);`

Comment: Great catch, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
Particle.publish("endGame", null, 60, PRIVATE);
```

you use something called `null`, and neither you nor the standard declares such a thing.

If this is supposed to pass a Null-Pointer, use

```
Particle.publish("endGame", nullptr, 60, PRIVATE);
```

or, if you are pre-C++11 and included an appropriate library,

```
Particle.publish("endGame", NULL, 60, PRIVATE);
```

Note that case is important in C++.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks for the explanation. Will mark as solved when the 5 minutes is up